# In-Page Analytics not working

Tags: google-analytics

When trying to look at In-Page Analytic in firefox I get this message:

"Problem loading In-Page Analytics
We've identified problems in your setup. These may cause problems loading In-Page Analytics.

1. Your site doesn't load ga.js from Google. If you host the Google tracking code on your own servers, it isn't updated automatically and can miss important changes.
2. We didn't find a tracking snippet on your site. In-Page Analytics cannot load. Please make sure you have tracking installed correctly. If your snippet is included in a separate JavaScript file, you'll have to manually check it is being loaded correctly."

When trying to view In-Page Analytic in Chrome I get:

"Access denied. Please try relaunching In-Page Analytics from the report.[Error: 20006]"

I don't understand why this is not working because when I look at other reports in Google Analytic like page views everything seems to be working fine...

Any help would be much appreciated.

Alex

[image: In-Page Analytics misleading error box]

Comment: I spent a long time trying to figure this out. Then I tried In-Page Analytics in Safari and it just worked. It seems like Chrome and Firefox have introduced increased security measures that are preventing this from working as it should...

Comment: @AlexLockwood yep, the most browsers block `http` scripts on `https` by default now.

Comment: @luk3thomas So then is it safe to assume that this is a bug on Google's end? Or is there something that we are doing wrong?

Answer (score 30):

Recent web browser updates block `http` scripts from loading in a `https` session by default. In the URL bar click the **shield** icon and *Load unsafe script* to show in page analytics.

[Credit](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!searchin/analytics/in-page$20analytics%7Csort:date/analytics/TkNm4yHXd_k/b9-TnbwY76gJ)

[image]

Comment: I agree that this is the first step towards a solution, but even after doing this I still get the following error in Chrome and Firefox: `Access denied. Please try relaunching In-Page Analytics from the report. [Error: 20004]` (screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/LrxQB2H.png).

Comment: @AlexLockwood whoops, I didn't read the question closely enough. I was googling to fix the problem myself. Sounds like you have a error with your tracking code.

Comment: Did you end up fixing the problem yourself? I've copied the _exact_ tracking code directly from the Admin console. Also, like I said earlier In-Page analytics works in Safari... but not in Chrome, Firefox, or Opera. This is driving me nuts... I'd appreciate it if you could look at the analytics code for [my site](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/)... maybe you will see something that I don't.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that I've recently upgraded to Universal Analytics... not sure if that has any effect here or not. I don't see why it would have any effect... but just wanted to put it out there.

Comment: @AlexLockwood Yes, my answer fixed the problem for me. Hmm, that is strange. This looks off: `ga('create', 'UA-32166730-1', 'androiddesignpatterns.com');` should probably be `ga('create', 'UA-32166730-1', 'www.androiddesignpatterns.com');`, but I'm not sure if that will actually help.

Comment: According to [this G+ post](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+AlexLockwood/posts/UrZvGzaVWmv), that shouldn't matter... but I will try it right now anyway, because at this point everything is pretty much just guess-work. :)

Comment: Adding the `www.` did nothing. Removing the `www.` seems to be consistent with the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/domains) as well. The Admin Console also tells me to copy and paste the tracking code exactly (so adding the `www.` to the tracking code would go against the directions given in the admin console). At this point, I have no clue... I guess it's not that important right now anyway. Maybe in a few months someone will figure something out...

Comment: It seems a little stupid that Google Chrome blocks Google analytics script from running. You'd think being part of the same company the two products would work together.

Comment: @AlexLockwood and now it's july 2016 and they still haven't fixed this.

Comment: This answer just solved my issue, which was exatly the same as the poster. :) Thanks!! Why is it not accepted yet?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem in Chrome and [this](http://trantor.synology.me/ruthpozuelo/site-doesnt-load-ga-js-google-page-analytics/) worked for me like a charm:

> After you try loading the report, look at the Chrome browser’s Address
>   bar.  At the right side of the bar, a shield icon is displayed.  Click
>   on the shield icon.  Then you’re notified that the site contains an
>   unsafe script, and you’re given the option to run the script.  Once
>   you grant permission to run the script, the report appears as it’s
>   supposed to

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Clear your browsing data and try again.  (Ctrl - Shift - Delete)

You should also verify your View settings are correct - please have a look at this GA troubleshooting document:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2559761?hl=en

Comment: Incorrect view settings were the culprit for me. The "Website's URL" field was set to HTTP instead of HTTPS.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue as user1697748 & Alex Lockwood. I change the property settings to 
Start In-Page Analytics in "Full View Mode" instead of embedded mode. 
This you can find in Admin --> Property Settings.

Now I the In page analytics opens in new window but get this error.

**Access denied. Please try relaunching In-Page Analytics from the report.[Error: 20006]**

I am getting the other data from analytic but having issues with in page analytics.

So I did following to fix it.

1. Make sure the url is same in all your properties. I had at one place http://www.studyn.us and at all other places it was http://studyn.us. Google also recommends to keep it same
   https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2559761?hl=en
2. Delete all cookies. Close windows and re open it.

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It has been more than 2 years since In-Page Analytics report started to have problems with loading the data in Google Analytics interface. There are a few things you can try:

1. You can disable the security in your browser (not recommended).
2. You can download a plugin for Chrome to view some of the Google Analytics data directly in your browser (you wouldn't be able to apply any segments or filter the data by using the plugin).
3. **You can recreate the report using Google Analytics data** (the best solution) in Excel or Tableau. It isn't very hard to do, and once you are done, the problem is gone forever.

Here is [a detailed step-by-step description of how to recreate In-Page Analytics report](http://www.analyticscanvas.com/create-page-analytics-report-using-google-analytics-api-tableau/).

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhfGr.png)

Answer (score 0):

Google anaytics inpage analytics feature has been disabled and will be removed soon. To overcome the loading errors a new page analytics chrome extension has been developed which is more easier to use and analyze page.

Follow the step by step guide to using [inpage analytics chrome extension](http://marketlytics.com/analytics-faq/using-inpage-analytics-chrome-extension).

Answer (score -3):

seems to be a widespread problem with this whole inpage analytics thing.
I had/ have several problems my self and there is not only one step towards the solution because there is more than just one problem. So I will write here some of the steps and solutions  I made so far which worked:
1. Problem: Access denied. Please try relaunching In-Page Analytics from the report.[Error: 20006] = Solution = If updated to universal analytics you get a code snippet, which is not complete: you get this from analytics 
ga('create', 'UA-1200274-1', 'sgo.ch');
ga('send', 'pageview');
but you have to put in an extra line between those two lines
**ga('require', 'linkid', 'linkid.js');**, plus you have to go under admin ->Property settings-> and switch on **Use enhanced link attribution**, **DONT** use full side mode!
Now when you try  inpage analytics again it depends on the browser you are using: In IE, it appears an allert, you have to click on "view whole content" (sorry I have it in german, it might be in english saying something else, like loading page, or show whole page or so..), In google Chrome you have to look in the url bar, there is kind of a shield and you have to click on it and say load unsecure script. 
Well that is the way how to solve the two error messages with **Access denied. Please try relaunching In-Page Analytics from the report.[Error: 20006]** and **"Problem loading In-Page Analytics We've identified problems in your setup. These may cause problems loading In-Page Analytics..."**
Now at least you can anaylse the **main page** (eg www.example.com), but in my case when i click further, then it doesnt stop loading for ever or it just appears that error again **Access denied. Please try relaunching In-Page Analytics from the report.[Error: 20006]**, 
I was really analyzing and testing and breaking my head, until I found out, that when I **copy the Url, at the end of the url, my webpages adress repeats again**. like this https://www.google.com/analytics/web/?hl=de&pli=1....**%2Fwww.example.com**/. so i **just deleted the last part from the www**... out of the Url and pressed enter and then all the datas appeared... Its a little annoying because you have to delete the www out of ech url you are anaylzing manually, but at least you can use the inpage analytics. Sorry for my very bad English skills, but I hope at least some one understood it:)
Please dont stop posting more solutions and ideas:)
regards MA