# In-page analytics requires ga.js instead of analytics.js

Tags: google-analytics

Recently I added the   ga('require', 'linkid', 'linkid.js');
in my analytics code.

This is my source code.

```
 (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-24190***-7', 'whitebeartest.com');
  ga('require', 'linkid', 'linkid.js');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
```

But when I tried in-page analytics,it requires ga.js

I think ga.js is downward compatibile of analytics.js

How can I use in-page analytics??

```
We've identified problems in your setup. These may cause problems loading In-Page Analytics.
Your site doesn't load ga.js from Google. If you host the Google tracking code on your own servers, it isn't updated automatically and can miss important changes.
We didn't find a tracking snippet on your site. In-Page Analytics cannot load. Please make sure you have tracking installed correctly. If your snippet is included in a separate JavaScript file, you'll have to manually check it is being loaded correctly.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [In-Page Analytics not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391203/in-page-analytics-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

You have me stumped on this one here are my ideas:

1. Did you remember to enable enhanced link attribution in your property settings?   [Enhanced Link Attribution](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2558867?hl=en)
2. Check the source code on your site are you running both classic and universal tracking code in there do you have a misplaced .push someplace?
3. Is your account still set to Classic analytics and now your trying to use the Universal analytics tracking code?   ga.js is classic analytics, analytics.js is universal analytics.  [Universal Analytics Upgrade Center](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/)

Comment: added 2 more ideas. I'm intrigued by this :). I'm leaning towards nr 3.

Comment: 2) ,only analytics.js is put in my site,and normal analytics works fine. 3) My account is aready upgraded, and admin->property->tracking code shows  universal analytics code correctly

Comment: Where does linkid.js come from?